# how to turn off (or hook to not show) drop down next to insert image in ckeditor 5 over pasted base64 stored image

Tags: ckeditor5

I tried my best but could not find a way how to disable this state:[image]
I enabled base64 image upload adapter (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/image-upload/base64-upload-adapter.html) and it works fine but in the demo here https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/image-upload/base64-upload-adapter.html I see that they use imageUpload command and I am using imageInsert in my setup in the pic above.

in my case it makes sense to also link images from image hosting we use so I let user paste in URL of image and let the browser render it. but I just can't find a way how to not display the base64 encoded image (content) since it is in src property and it basically works as expected but user can damage the image and also can be puzzled what he sees. yes I understand user can undo what he did and have the picture back, but just double checking if there is a better way.

any idea ladies? thx.

I searched help but no luck and not sure if I want to change ckeditor 5 sources and make my own build.